# Google App Engine PHP SDK Libraries Include Error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework, autoload

Excuse my ignorance and possibly blindness... maybe I've been staring at this way too long.

I have a Zend Framework app running on Google App Engine, and since this morning, a lot of the functionality of my deployed app broke down. My fatherly instinct is to blame some change on the run time... but I'm possibly doing something silly and not seeing it:

**My issue**

The way I'm using some of the helper PHP libraries included in the SDK is by saving all the files in my Zend project under /project-root/library/google/appengine/api, then including them throughout my project as needed:

```
<?php

require_once LIBRARY_PATH."/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php";
```

Things used to work fine this way, but today I now get the following error in the live app:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class google\appengine\BlobstoreServiceError in
/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project-id/1.37159836030638885
     /library/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore_service_pb.php on line 73
```

If I simply comment that *require_once* out of my file, it works fine live, but obviously gives a 404 on my development environment. My current solution, which I'm hoping someone can help me improve is to include the library like thus:

```
if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
   require_once LIBRARY_PATH."/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php";
}
```

**My question**

What's going on?! How could I tweak my dev environment to load those classes without me having to manually include them?

Comment: Please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075747/class-google-appengine-createuploadurlrequest-not-found